# Is it useful to extend List<E> in this case?

Tags: java, list, oop, generics, java-8

Consider I have the following code:

```
public interface Drawable {
    public void compileProgram();

    public Program getProgram();

    public int getDataSize();

    public FloatBuffer putData(final FloatBuffer dataBuffer);

    public int getDataMode();

    public void draw(final int offset);

    public void delete();

    public static int countDataSize(final Collection<Drawable> drawables) {
        return drawables.stream()
                .mapToInt(Drawable::getDataSize)
                .sum();
    }

    public static FloatBuffer putAllData(final List<Drawable> drawables) {
        FloatBuffer dataBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(countDataSize(drawables) * 3);
        for (Drawable drawable : drawables) {
            drawable.putData(dataBuffer);
        }
        return (FloatBuffer)dataBuffer.clear();
    }

    public static void drawAll(final List<Drawable> drawables) {
        int offset = 0;
        for (Drawable drawable : drawables) {
            drawable.draw(offset);
            offset += drawable.getDataSize();
        }
    }

    public static void deleteAll(final List<Drawable> drawables) {
        drawables.stream().forEach(Drawable::delete);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Terrain implements Drawable { ... }

public class Floor implements Drawable { ... }
```

And I use it as the follows:

```
private final Terrain terrain;
private final Floor floor;
private final List<Drawable> drawables;

public FPSGameController(final int screenWidth, final int screenHeight, final boolean debug) {
    super(screenWidth, screenHeight, debug);

    this.terrain = new Terrain();
    this.floor = new Floor();
    this.drawables = new ArrayList<>();

    drawables.add(terrain);
    drawables.add(floor);
}

...

@Override
protected void render(final double msDelta) {
    super.render(msDelta);

    glClearColor(25f / 255f, 25f / 255f, 112f / 225f, 1.0f);
    glClearDepthf(1f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    Drawable.drawAll(drawables);
}
```

Would it then be a correct approach to create a class:

```
public class DrawableList extends List<Drawable> { ... }
```

that implements the functionality that is currently static in the `Drawable` interface?

Also: Does my implementation currently perform some practice that generally is against coding standards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of static methods in your interface `Drawable` seems good. As I know, it is possible to write static methods into interfaces (with Java 8) in order to avoid static classes like `Collections` or whatever.

To answer your question about the `DrawableList`, it is probably a bad idea. There are two reasons:

- You are manipulating a lot of `List<Drawable>`, obviously. But when you want to implement an `ArrayList`, a `Stack`, a `LinkedList` or whatever, to get better performances, you will be happy to keep your current implementation.
- If you extends `List<Drawable>`, remember you will never change this in your program without a lot of refactoring. And the day you need to extend an other class (for better reasons), you can do nothing.

Nevertheless, you can create an object `DrawableList`, which will manipulate a list:

```java
public class DrawableList {
    private List<Drawable> list;
}
```

And in this class, you can call `List` methods by defining your own methods.

Comment: +1 Modern OOP generally prefers composition over inheritance.

Comment: Would there be any advice to either of the use of `DrawableList` (composition) or the `static` methods in the interface?

Comment: Whether one method should be preferred over the other, are there any arguments to use the one over the other?

Comment: It really depends on what you have to do. If your code manipulate the object himself, use non-static methods. If your code is mainly related to your class (and not to your object), use static methods. One more advise: implement the non-static method which are related to `DrawableList` into the class `DrawableList` and not into the interface `Drawable`.